# Is the set function inside setState hook immutable?

Tags: reactjs

If I have something like `const [x, setX] = useState(0)`. My question is whenever I use `setX()`, is the value of `x` immutable?

Comment: `Is the value of x immutable`? you define it as a `const` so I think you have your answer :) But yes, you shouldn't be doing straight mutations to the state value. I.e, `x = 1`. Thats why you have a setter `setX(1)`. Use the setter to update your value, this is essentially providing class `state` functionality to a functional component

Comment: Each time you use `setX` the value of `x` will be updated with the value you pass as an argument to `setX`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you can examine two objects regarding their immutability:

1. value hold by x
2. the tuple created by `useState`, which holds x at first index in `[x, setX]`

Immutability according to wikipedia:

> In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

So if you can alter the state of these objects after creation, they are not considered immutable. In your example, they are immutable, as `x` is a primitive and you use `const`/destructuring assignment. But in principle `useState` hook does not prevent you from mutating both.

For 1.) You can/should declare the variable holding the tuple of `useState` always with access modifier `const`/destructuring assignment to prevent altering.

For 2.) Lets presume, x is an object `{a: number}`. You *can* mutate properties in x directly without `setX` (like `x.a = 42`). In this case React will not be aware of the change, but the property value of `x` actually has changed.

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-currying-43ccw).

```
function App() {
  let [x, setX] = useState({ a: 0 });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {x.a}</h1>
      <h2 onClick={() => setX({ a: x.a + 1 })}>Increment by setX</h2>
      <h2 onClick={() => (x.a = x.a + 1)}>Increment by mutation</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope that helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), where the previous value of x is given as a parameter to the setX function, x should treated as immutable. The state should always be treated as immutable.

Hopefully this is illustrative:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [x, setX] = useState({foo: 'foo'});

  // x is immutable here

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setX(prevX => {

          // prevX is also immutable here

          // Use Object.assign or spread syntax to avoid mutating prevX
          return {...prevX, bar: 'bar'}
        }
      }>
        Add bar
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```